# Invalid principal in policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Whenever I run for the first time the following terraform file I do get the error:

**Error creating IAM Role SecurityMonkey: MalformedPolicyDocument: Invalid principal in policy: "AWS".**

However, wen I execute the code the a second time the execution succeed creating the assume role object. To me it looks like there's some problems with dependencies between role A and role B. As a remedy I've put  even a depends_on statement on the role A but with no luck.

SecurityMonkeyInstanceProfile

Here you can check my TF code.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "SecurityMonkey" {
name               = "SecurityMonkey"
depends_on = ["aws_iam_role.SecurityMonkeyInstanceProfile"]
path               = "/"
assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
  "Sid": "",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<AccountID>:role/SecurityMonkeyInstanceProfile"
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }
  ]
}
POLICY
}


resource "aws_iam_role" "SecurityMonkeyInstanceProfile" {
name               = "SecurityMonkeyInstanceProfile"
path               = "/"
assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
 }
 ]
 }
 POLICY
 }
```

First run with error.

```
aws_iam_role.SecurityMonkey: Error creating IAM Role SecurityMonkey: MalformedPolicyDocument: Invalid principal in policy: "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::<AccountID>:role/SecurityMonkeyInstanceProfile"
    status code: 400, request id: 0810c923-28dd-11e6-af5d-47689d50861a
```

Second run without error.

```
terraform apply  -var-file=../../aws.tfvars
aws_iam_role.SecurityMonkeyInstanceProfile: Refreshing state... (ID: SecurityMonkeyInstanceProfile)
aws_iam_role.SecurityMonkey: Creating...
  arn:                "" => "<computed>"
  assume_role_policy: "" => "{\n  \"Version\": \"2008-10-17\",\n  \"Statement\": [\n    {\n      \"Sid\": \"\",\n      \"Effect\": \"Allow\",\n      \"Principal\": {\n        \"AWS\": \"arn:aws:iam::<AccountID>:role/SecurityMonkeyInstanceProfile\"\n      },\n      \"Action\": \"sts:AssumeRole\"\n    }\n  ]\n}\n"
  name:               "" => "SecurityMonkey"
  path:               "" => "/"
  unique_id:          "" => "<computed>"
aws_iam_role.SecurityMonkey: Creation complete

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Clearly the resources are created in the right order but seems there's some sort of timeout that makes `SecurityMonkeyInstanceProfile` role not discoverable by `SecurityMonkey` role. Pretty much a chicken and egg problem.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Which terraform version did you run with?

If it is already the latest version, then I will guess the time gap between two resources is too short, the API system hasn't enough time to report the new resource `SecurityMonkeyInstanceProfile` to be created when the second resource creation follow up already.

Try to add a sleep function and let me know if this can fix your issue or not.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "SecurityMonkeyInstanceProfile" {
  ...
  provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "sleep 10"
    }
}
```

refer the bug report: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/1885

Comment: Hi, 

thanks for your reply. I've tried the sleep command without success even before opening the question on SO. Anyhow I've raised an issue on Github,

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/7076